# MySQL backup and restore with views

Tags: mysql, database, import

I am having trouble getting mysql backups to run properly when their are views in the database.  I think this might have something to do with needing a placeholder object for it.   In any event I run this command:

```
mysqldump -u myuser -pmypassword mydatabase | mysql -u myuser -pmypassword -C mydatabase_Beta
```

The user has full privileges and I get this:

> View mydatabase_beta.yadayada references invalid tables or columns or functions or definer/invoker or view lack rights to use them.

How can I back it up so that it restores all of my database properly?

In the example I am restoring it to a different name but I do need to be able to restore a working copy.  I think it is probably an additional mysqldump parameter or maybe hot copy would work better.  Thoughts?

Comment: Does the config you reference cause mysql to load the data to a separate instance?  Does it help to save the dumpfile and then attempt to pipe it to mysql as a second step?  Is there any difference in versions or supported storage engines between the two instances if there are two?

Comment: I removed the -C, I do not need it, same issue though.  Restoring to the exact same host/instance

Comment: Are you getting the error on the dump or the import?

Answer (score 2):

Try doing it in two steps first:

```
mysqldump -uroot -ppassword --skip-extended-insert database.sql > database.sql
```

So it backs up to a file and then pipe that into the second command:

```
mysql -u myuser -pmypassword -C mydatabase_Beta < database.sql
```

If the reference error is in the mysqldump step either fix the views or drop it from the database.  I can't imaging they're still used if they reference a non-existing table.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer might be to add `-f`:

```
--force, -f

Continue even if an SQL error occurs during a table dump.
```

One use for this option is to cause mysqldump to continue executing even when it encounters a view that has become invalid because the definition refers to a table that has been dropped. Without `--force`, mysqldump exits with an error message. With `--force`, mysqldump prints the error message, but it also writes an SQL comment containing the view definition to the dump output and continues executing.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark here, but I don't think you need the `-C` in the second half of that statement. According to my copy of mysql `-C` defines the config file path to use.

Comment: Removed -C as I did not need it, still has issue with creating one of my views.